# Apache mod_rewrite clashing with wordpress rule

Tags: wordpress, apache, mod-rewrite

I have a page outside of the Wordpress installing but located in the root directory at v1.html

I've tried a few different mod_rewrite rules but they all seem to clash with the WordPress .htaccess rules. How can I keep my wordpress installation in tact but also have /v1.html renamed to /v1 without 404ing

```
    # BEGIN WordPress
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

    </IfModule>

    # END WordPress
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your rule before the WordPress block and use the `[L]` to stop on your rule when it matches. This way it doesn't trickle into the WordPress rules.

```apache
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^v1/?$ /v1.html [L]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Thank you! Really helpful :).